# Sending a UDP datagram to a shared IP address and port

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, ip, nat

Suppose that two computers use the same Wi-Fi to access the Internet. Each of these computers has the same program installed, which is bound to the same UDP port. I want to know, since both computers have the same external IP address and listen to the same port but on different machines, what will be the result if a UDP datagram is sent to this common external address and to a common port, then which machine will receive it and how to send it each machine its own personal datagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router will not forward the packet to either computer, since it doesn't know which one it should forward to.

In fact, even if the program was only running on one computer, the router still wouldn't forward the packet. It has to see outbound traffic going from the computer to the outside world first, before it decides which external port to use for forwarding inbound traffic back to the computer. And the router might not decide to use the same port on the public IP that the computer used on the private IP.

This is why everyone hates NAT and likes IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this mean that if both of these computers first contact the remote computer via UDP, then the router will complete this task and each machine will be able to receive its own datagram? If yes, then it is interesting to know the technical side of this issue, because UDP does not imply a network connection.

Comment: @John the router will pick a different public port for each connection. NAT routers have to *guess* UDP connections, which is just another reason NAT is completely terrible. It will probably count the connection as disconnected if no packet is sent or received for a few minutes.

Comment: That is, when sending a datagram, each machine will set a different port and on these ports the remote computer will be able to send datagrams to each computer separately? If so, is there any guarantee that both machines will not select the same port?

Comment: @John the NAT router changes the port number just like it changes the IP address.

Comment: Okay, so this will work. Will NAT be able to select different ports if I force a specific port in a C/C++ program using the bind function?

Comment: @John yes because the bind function only affects the port your computer chooses and has no effect on the router.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Fast and informative. In this case, I wonder if it makes sense to call the bind function if, in the end, it does not play any role in this case?

Comment: @John It rarely makes sense to bind a specific port if you are not a server. I don't remember whether it's mandatory for UDP, but in either case you can bind to port 0 to tell the OS to choose a port for you.

Comment: OK, thank you so much! As i know, port binding for UDP is optional. If this is not done, then the OS itself will assign the port dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, but what if I need to install a program on these two machines that should work as both a UDP server and a UDP client? What happens if one of these machines tries to send a datagram to a second machine? I will need to use the bind function and listen on the same port on both machines, and I will need to specify my external IP address as the server address when sending the datagram. In general, I need to be able to send datagrams both between machines that use the same Wi-Fi, and with any other machine, which can be a remote server and have a different external IP address.